# Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_HENV failed while connecting extremeDB ODBC driver

Tags: database, unixodbc

**Getting the following error while running
isql EXDB -v
[IM004][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_HENV failed
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect**

```
Below are contents of odbc.ini 
[EXDB]
Description = eXtremeSQL data source
Driver = eXtremeSQL
#DATABASE = exdb
SERVER = localhost:5099
```

```
odbcinst.ini : 
[eXtremeSQL]
Description = ODBC for eXtremeSQL
Driver =
Setup =
Driver64 = /root/extremeDB-v8.0.1799.25104.1/odbc/bin.so/libmcoodbc_drv_debug.so
Setup64 =
FileUsage = 1
```

isql command is giving some error. Please help

Comment: Please, provide details about the error(s).

Comment: This is the only detail I could see
[IM004][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_HENV failed
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect